# iOS UI Testing with device camera

Tags: ios, testing, camera, uitest

I have a suite of UITests and one test needs to use the camera. It is very flaky as if testing on device, the camera must be able to focus and get a picture the first time. It is also frustrating as I have to skip the test when running on Fastlane (or otherwise in an automated fashion using the simulator).

What is best practice for UITesting user behaviour dependent on the camera?

An example of my test code is below:

```
func testAddWithCamera() {

    if Platform.isSimulator {

        print("Test skipped as no camera on simulator")
    } else {

        let app = XCUIApplication()
        app.buttons["Camera"].tap()
        app.buttons["PhotoCapture"].tap()
        app.buttons["Use Photo"].tap()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any tests involving the camera. But could you describe more specifically what issue(s) you're having? "best practice" is broad. If you're doing some kind of image recognition, you might want to take a mock object route and feed in known good or known bad images and ensure the correct behavior for those cases. Otherwise your tests are going to be highly dependent on the camera hardware, lighting conditions, lens clarity, etc. and those factors might not be relevant to what you're testing.